# Force div in flex display to be 50% of screen when second div is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a structure like this one with one div containing two others:

```
<div class="list-detail">
    <div class='first-list'>
 
    </div>
    <div class='second-list'>
 
    </div>
</div>
```

I am populating them using jquery and their css looks like this:

```
.list-detail{
    display:flex;
}
.event-list, .match-list{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

The `width:100%` allows the divs to span the entire screen with width 50% of the screen each.
The div `second-list` can be empty, and if so I hide it. The problem comes when it is hidden, the div `first-list` takes the entirety of the screen, and in this situtation I would like the div to be centered and taking 50% of the screen. How can I achieve this?

I already tried removing/modifying the `width:100%`, since it is probably the reason why it spans the entire screen when the div `second-list` is hidden but then it messes up the use case where both divs are full with elements. They are very small / not centered at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could set visibility to hidden but keep in mind it will hide it from UI but this div will still take up space, you could see this in example below

Alternatively, you could set flex basis to 50% on list element and set display to none on the ones you want to hide or remove them from DOM

Depending on what you want to achieve you could also checkout how to do it with grid

```css
.list-detail {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.first-list,
.second-list {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.first-list {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-detail">
  <div class='first-list'>

  </div>
  <div class='second-list'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to center the div.first-list when the div.second-list is empty, and you also want the div.first-list to be at 50% of the space,
here is the solution

```js
    
    let second = $('.second-list').text();
    if(second.length == 0){
      $('.second-list').remove();
    }
```

```css
.list-detail{
    display:flex;
}
.first-list, .second-list{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-detail">
    <div class='first-list'>
 Magna adipisicing consequat reprehenderit culpa. Tempor aliquip enim occaecat nisi officia amet ex quis. Culpa esse consectetur eiusmod excepteur commodo sint velit cupidatat enim consequat enim officia mollit exercitation.
    </div>
  <div class='second-list'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: to center it when the second div is empty

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: I used $(document).ready because you said you are using jquery, you might as well not do it, it still works

Comment: yes you can also not use IIFE, I have updated the code snippet for you